# Remove a single value from a NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, namevaluecollection

My data source could have duplicate keys with values.

```
typeA : 1

typeB : 2

typeA : 11
```

I chose to use `NameValueCollection` as it enables entering duplicate keys.

I want to remove specific key\value pair from the collection, but `NameValueCollection.Remove(key)` removes all values associated with the specified key.

1. Is there a way to remove single key\value pair from a `NameValueCollection`, 
   OR
2. Is there a better collection in C# that fits my data

**[EDIT 1]**

First, thanks for all the answers :)

I think I should have mentioned that my data source is XML.

I used `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` to query for type and also it was handy to remove a particular value.

Now, my question is, for large size data, is using XDocument a good choice considering the performance? 
If not what are other alternatives (maybe back to NameValueCollection and using one of the techniques mentioned to remove data)

Comment: Nope I think it will not work with index of element, probably you need to try out some other way

Comment: Try `List<Tuple<T1,T2>>`

Comment: There is literally **no way to do this**.  If you do have to do it, simply iterate through the whole thing, making a whole new NameValueCollection.  NameValueCollection is amazingly powerful, but, like all specific collections, it is built to do a specific job, and some things simply cannot be done with it.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of storing multiple values with the same key is somehow strange. But I think you can retrieve all values using GetValues then remove the one you don't need and put them back using Set and then subsequent Add methods. You can make a separate extension method method for this.

Answer (score 1):

`NameValueCollection` doesn't really allow to have multiple entries with the same key. It merely concatenates the new values of existing keys into a comma separated list of values (see [NameValueCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsc9a449.aspx).

So there really is just a single value per key. You could conceivably get the value split them on ',' and remove the offending value.

`Edit: @ElDog is correct, there is a GetValues method which does this for you so no need to split.`

A better option I think would be to use `Dictionary<string, IList<int>>` or `Dictionary<string, ISet<int>>` to store the values as discrete erm, values

Answer (score 0):

You may convert it to Hashtable

```
           var x = new NameValueCollection();
           x.Add("a", "1");
           x.Add("b", "2");
           x.Add("a", "1");
           var y = x.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k=>x[k]);
```

Comment: The dictionary will contain the values ["a", "1,1"] and ["b", "2"]. That is probably not the what Ayman is after.

Answer (score 0):

make your own method, it works for me --

```
public static void Remove<TKey,TValue>(
  this List<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> list,
  TKey key,
  TValue value) {
  return list.Remove(new KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>(key,value)); 
}
```

then call it on list as --

```
list.Remove(key,value); //Pass the key value...
```

Comment: This solution only works if `EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default` and `EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default` yield correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the best way, but....

```
public class SingleType
{
    public string Name;
    public int Value;
}

List<SingleType> typeList = new List<SingleType>();
typeList.Add (new SingleType { Name = "TypeA", Value = 1 });
typeList.Add (new SingleType { Name = "TypeA", Value = 3 });

typeList.Remove (typeList.Where (t => t.Name == "TypeA" && t.Value == 1).Single());
```

Comment: `Single()` throws an exception if there isn't one element in the list. This should be ok: `var val = typeList.Where (t => t.Name == "TypeA" && t.Value == 1).SingleOrDefault(); if (val != null) typeList.Remove (val);`

Comment: Yeah sorry, should have mentioned that - just knocked together the code very quickly....however throwing a (caught) exception might be handy here to indicate there has been an attempt to delete invalid data IMO.

Comment: Yes, this depends on whether the user considers "attempting to delete invalid data" _exceptional_

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Dictionary collection instead:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary.Add("typeA", 1);
dictionary.Add("typeB", 1);
```

When you try to insert `type: 11` it will throw exception as Key already exists. So you can enter a new key to insert this data.

Refer this [Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary) for further help.